# Calculating a future date

Tags: java, date, datetime

I have created a program to calculate days and in my program i want add 7 more days to the current date.

Which means if today's date is 9/11/2013, i want to make it 9/18/2013 by getting the current date and adding 7 more days to it. How do i implement this.

I know how to get today's date by using the date class but i don't know to add another 7 days to the current date.

This is the method i used to get the current date :

```
 public void dateCalculator(){
    Date date;
    date=new Date();
           }
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

c.setTime(new Date()); // Now use today date.

c.add(Calendar.DATE, 15); // Adds 15 days
```

Comment: By default, the new `Calendar` instance will have the current time, and you'll need `getTime()` to get the `Date` out.

Answer (score 18):

you can get that by `Calendar#add(Calender.DATE,7)`

code snippet -

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println("current date: " + cal.getTime());
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 7);
System.out.println("7 days later: " + cal.getTime());
```

result -

```
current date: Tue Sep 10 15:53:17 MST 2013
7 days later: Tue Sep 17 15:53:17 MST 2013
```

Note: code compiled in - http://www.compileonline.com/compile_java_online.php

Comment: Thanks that worked

Comment: worked elegantly even after so many years..thats the beauty of Java